# What is FOVx in this diagram?

Tags: 3d, matrix, software-rendering

a beginner game developer here. I have recently taken upon learning about 3D game development and I am stuck on a simple matrix problem.

[image: diagram]

The image is found from this article: http://www.codinglabs.net/article_world_view_projection_matrix.aspx

I am trying to represent this matrix in my code but I am not sure what precisely is meant by FOVx and FOVy. What is the difference and how would I represent this in my perspective matrix? I am not using any 3D api.

Comment: FOV is [Field Of View](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fov).

Comment: I understand that part, but how do I get the x and the y? What is the difference? I thought the FOV was just an angle

Comment: It's two angles actually: one horizontal (the `x` component), one vertical (`y`). For example, to emulate human vision, you might want to have a camera that can "see" a somewhat greater horizontal angle than vertically.

Comment: Ah thank you, that actually clarifies things a lot more. I always assumed that the FOV was just a single angle.

Comment: That's pretty much the extent of my knowledge on projection matrices though! :) If you figure out the rest (or if that actually answers the question; I can't really tell), it's totally OK to post answers on your own questions too.

Comment: I believe what you said really clarified it for me, however; I am still slightly unsure of the answer for the question, but thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's wiki on topic: [Field of view in video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view_in_video_games)

[image]

X and Y angles can be set separately to allow for wide/tall views. For example if you need a panorama for 3 displays like so, with default FOVy, but 120 degrees FOVx:

[image]

Comment: One information you might also want to provide is which unit you need to provide the FOV in when building a projection matrix. I *think* it is in radian. Is this correct?

Comment: It depends on math functions implementation. Usually they expect angles in radians, but that is not always so.

Comment: Thank you, and in my implementation it is specifying the angles in radians. However, I just convert them to radians in the function itself so whomever is using the function can pass the angle in degrees.